# Spring Boot - Config client application name

Tags: java, spring-boot, config

I am creating a basic client/server configured app in Spring Boot, but when I start my client app, I have this:

```
...  INFO [bootstrap,,,] ... Fetching config from server at: http://myConfig.com:8080
...  INFO [bootstrap,,,] ... ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=application, profiles=[default], label=master, version=..., state=null
```

EDIT: The problem is that I configured my app name with **my-app**, so I was expecting **name=my-app** instead of *name=application*. So **the client is not getting the expected configuration**.

EDIT2: The config server is running in an exclusive VM, so the 8080 port is available (just for the config server). There is nothing else running in my config server.

I read some posts, and I could mark the following items:

1) I have

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

in my **pom.xml** file

2) My bootstrap.properties, located in **my-app\src\main\resources** has the following content:

```
spring.application.name=my-app
server.port=8080
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://myConfig.com:8080
```

3) When I access http://myConfig.com:8080/my-app/default/master with my browser, I get the corresponding configuration, so the server is working properly.

4) My config server had an ***application.properties*** in the past, but not now (I thought that it was the problem -a default property file-, but I refreshed and the problem is still there)

5) The problem appears the first time I run my app, I guess is not related to a health check.

Do you have any ideas about why the app is trying to say "**name=application**" instead of the real name? What I missed in my setup? 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT3: More data:
My config server is returning this:

```
{"name":"my-app","profiles":["default"],"label":"master","version":"...","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"file://myPath/my-app.properties","source":{"spring.rabbitmq.username":"MYUSER","spring.datasource.url":"jdbc:postgresql://someData?ssl=true","spring.datasource.username":"MyUser","spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto":"update","security.user.name":"MyUser2","spring.datasource.driverClassName":"org.postgresql.Driver", AND OTHER SPECIFIC DATA...}}]}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Do explain what is the issue clearly.

Comment: On what port is your config server running ? Not 8080 I hope ?!

Comment: this spring.cloud.config.uri=http://myConfig.com:8080 should be looking like this: spring.cloud.config.uri=http://myConfig.com:8001 (your config server port)

Comment: @georgesvan whats wrong with running the config server on 8080?

Comment: @MarcosTonina could you provide the response of  http://myConfig.com:8080/my-app/default/master ?

Comment: I added more data to the post. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the cloud config uri  In your  my-app properties file.  The maven dependency is enough.

Comment: follow this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298657/spring-cloud-config-client-not-fetching-config-when-spring-security-is-active-on
, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but adding `spring.application.name=my-app` inside the `bootstrap.properties` resolved my issue.

```
$ cat src/main/resources/bootstrap.properties
spring.application.name=my-app
spring.profiles.active=dev
$
$ java -jar build/libs/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
...
2024-01-29T12:14:08.447+09:00  INFO 28128 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=my-app, profiles=[default,dev], label=null, version=null, state=null
...
2024-01-29T12:14:46.750+09:00  INFO 28128 --- [tGr-eUnn23Oag-1] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Located environment: name=my-app, profiles=[dev], label=null, version=null, state=null
...
```

Technically, `bootstrap.properties` is loaded by a parent Spring `ApplicationContext`. That parent `ApplicationContext` is loaded before the one that uses `application.properties`.