# Why bootstrap.properties is ignored by spring-cloud-starter-config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

**My goal is to get the config for `world-service` from a `config-service`.**

The architecture:

1. `config-service` with dependency `spring-cloud-config-server` at `localhost:8888`
2. `world-service` with dependency the `spring-web` and `spring-cloud-starter-config`.

What I have done:

1. I have set up the Config Server and send a GET request to `http://localhost:8888/hello-service/master` and the config server get the `hello-service.properties` from [the config-repo repository](https://github.com/kidfrom/learn-spring-cloud-config). (If you need the `config-service`'s source code, I will push it to [this repository](https://github.com/kidfrom/learn-spring-cloud).)

My expected result:
The `world-service` use port 8081.

My actual result:
The `world-service` use port 8080.

bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=world-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>world-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>world-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-M5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With Spring Cloud 2020, they made a change in how bootstrap works and you have to include a new starter: `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap`.

Comment: Do you mean adding `   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>` to pom.xml? Thank you for pointing it out, I tried to google it but could not found any explanation. I also got an error when tried to add it to pom.xml `Cannot resolve org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:3.0.0-M5`

Comment: @kidfrom It looks correct. This a c&p from mine: <dependency>   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId><version>3.0.0-M5</version></dependency>

Comment: @kidfrom it's in the milestone repo: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap/3.0.0-M5/

Comment: @kidfrom see info from the cloud team about the topic here: https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/07/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-m4-aka-ilford-is-available

Comment: Thank you, it's fixed. Thank you for the help. The issue was somehow maven decided to use `offline mode`. I switch it off and its fixed. Anyway it's 2 AM, I will keep you updated at 5 AM.

Comment: Or use the new spring.config.import https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes

Answer (score 16):

I spent a day on it and finally found a solution. It may help others

You need to add new dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

According to the [Spring Cloud 2020.0](https://spring.io/blog/2020/10/07/spring-cloud-2020-0-0-m4-aka-ilford-is-available)

> Bootstrap, provided by spring-cloud-commons, is no longer enabled by
> default. If your project requires it, it can be re-enabled by
> properties or by a new starter.
>
> To re-enable by properties set spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true or
> spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true. These need to be set as an
> environment variable, java system property or a command line argument.
> The other option is to include the new spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap
> (in your POM file).

I used the first option and that worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

Spring Boot 2.4 introduced a new way to import configuration data via the spring.config.import property. This is now the default way to bind to Config Server.

To connect to config server set the following in application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: APPLICATION_NAME
  config:
    import: optional:configserver:http://USER:PASSWORD@MY_HOST:PORT/
```

You can see more details in: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/3.0.0/reference/html/#config-data-import

Comment: People who were downvoting this answer were wrong. Bootstrap is deprecated as of Spring Boot 2.4, and no longer enabled by default. You can re-enable it per the accepted answer, but in the future it will be removed and the way described in this answer is the new default.

Comment: @Mzzl where did you see that bootstrap is deprecated?  I see it is no longer the default, but I don't see any mention of deprecation...?

Comment: @LarryW I was looking for that source too saying it's been deprecated and don't see it mentioned on the Spring blog or in the source code.

Comment: It's not deprecated. Spring changed the behavior. Read about it here
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_the_bootstrap_application_context